# When writing by hand, can kana be half-width and kanji be full-width?

Tags: orthography, kana, handwriting

Simply I find when I'm writing I can only make kanji so small before they become sloppy, but I can write kana nice and small. Is it allowed to write half-width Katakana/Hiragana alongside regular width Kanji?

If you can how would this work horizontally and vertically?
If not, what's the point of half-width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably varies from person to person, at least a little bit, but **generally each character should be approximately the same size as any others (i.e. full-width)**. If you don't, especially with katakana (which are formed from pieces of kanji), you can end up with situations where **you cannot tell whether something is kana or kanji**. For example

> - ﾒﾘ vs 刈
> - ｶﾛ vs 加
> - and probably many others that don't come to mind immediately.

I'm not entirely sure what the general use of half-width kana is; the only places I have ever seen it used is in places that are never mixed with kanji, such as the name input for a bank transfer at an ATM (my name is also recorded in half-width katakana in my bank book). Many websites also explicitly require you to input the reading of your name in full-width kana, as well.

I would say that the general rule of **always use full-width unless explicitly told otherwise** is probably safe.

Answer (score 1):

In usual handwriting, kana often turn out smaller than full-fledged kanji, especially kanji with many strokes. (Though practising writing both kanji and kana the same size is probably an important step towards achieving a nice balance between kanji and kana size.)

Some fonts have comparatively small katakana, which I find very easy to read.

[image: small katakana in the book 時をかける少女]

<sub>This is from the book 時をかける少女, 角川文庫</sub>

I don't think half-width katakana have anything to do with handwriting. Half-width kana are squashed in the horizontal direction by a factor of two and used for saving space in typed documents (e.g. on 通帳, in ATMs, etc.), when choosing a small enough font size would be too small to read easily. I don't really recall seeing half-width kana mixed with kanji.

In any case, I think it's fine to write kana a little smaller than kanji, but I don't think you should aim for squashing your kana horizontally.